# Veracrypt boot drive fails after Windows Update with “cannot find winload.efi”

Tags: windows-10, boot, veracrypt

After having run through a Windows 10 update again, the next time I tried to boot my machine, it immediately complained in a blue screen about being unable to find the "winload.efi" file.

Instead I'd expect it to ask for my Veracrypt password and start booting afterwards.

There are some options offered, like pressing ESC or return or F8 to get to several options that may fix the problem.

I am worried about my data, what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

To future myself:

Veracrypt (at least if installed in a reasonably recent version) is able to survive windows updates, and the good news is that not every Windows update will react in this way. But if it does:

Last time you encountered this problem, this workflow helped:

Press ESC, wait a moment for Windows to show another menu, go to "Select a Boot Drive" and there select the Veracrypt Boot entry. Done. The machine will start again and immediately ask for the Veracrypt password.

Enter the password, and everything works again.

To avoid this issue in the future, when doing an update, make sure to properly restart the machine. This problem seems to appear if you put your machine into hibernation instead of rebooting it, so after the fix reboot again to be sure it has stored any changes on the disk drive.

(Hint: I am unable to correctly rephrase the exact menu points, as I just managed to fix the problem, without being able to reproduce, but I assume my future me will benefit regardless. Also consider that these options may be renamed anyways.)